Проверка значения атрибута через регулярные выражения + typing.Literal
Есть следующий код:
PropertyT = TypeVar('PropertyT')

class GenericSort(GenericModel, Generic[PropertyT]):
    attributeName: PropertyT

sorting_model = GenericSort[Literal['id', 'name']]

Возможно ли как-то к id и name добавить регулярное выражение типа
'attribute\..+'

чтобы среди атрибутов сортировки можно было задать attribute.любое_название?
Дальше sorting_model используется с pydantic.main create_model и conlist, чтобы было ограничение вводимых данных, и необходимо иметь возможность вводить строки вроде attribute.любое_название. Что будет написано на месте любое_название заранее не известно
